# Круглые края у Progress Bar только по краям, как?

Tags: css, foundation

Просьба подсказать, как сделать, чтобы у Progress Bar (Foundation 5), имеющего несколько значений, радиус был в начале и в конце (слева у первого и справа у последнего).
То есть, можно так сделать, например, но это если использовать простой вид, без progress radius (или round):

```
.progress { 
    border-radius: 20px; 
} 

.meter:first-child { 
    border-radius: 20px 0px 0px 20px; 
} 

.meter:last-child { 
    border-radius: 0px 20px 20px 0px; 
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: круглые края только по краям? а можно картинку?

Answer (score 0):

Наверное вот так:

```css
.progress { 
    border-radius: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #a00 33%, #aa0 33%, #aa0 66%, #0a0 66%)
}
```

```html
<div class="progress"></div>
```

---

Или так:

```css
.progress { 
    border-radius: 25px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 400px;
} 

.meter {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.333%;
    background-color: #aa0;
} 

.meter:first-child {
    background-color: #a00;
} 

.meter:last-child {
    background-color: #0a0;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress">
  <div class="meter">&nbsp;</div><div class="meter">&nbsp;</div><div class="meter">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и примеры! Но почему-то кажется, что это не совсем то.

Comment: @Plutooo что Вас не устраивает?